# Squeeze a time series to fit in a range while maintaining shape

Tags: time-series, polynomial, transform

I have the following time series with intermediate highs and lows marked by the vertical lines:

[image]

I want to transform/squeeze the series so that the resulting series would fit in a range, let's say **[0,1]** where the intermediate high and low points touch (or approximately touch) the edge of the range.

Here's an extremely ugly approximation of this for the above graph where the highs (marked by red lines) equate to the black line low hitting the top of the range and vice versa for the lows (green lines).

[image]

Is there a way to do this (like finding a polynomial function, which is then multiplied by the series) while still largely maintaining the shape and minor fluctuations?

Comment: Can we assume that there is always a trough between two peaks, and a peak between two troughs? And can we assume that the very first and the very last point are either a peak or a trough?

Comment: I think knowing why might help here?  Is this just for visual/aesthetic purposes?  I mean the obvious thing to do is just to cut the series into pieces between those highs and lows and scale each piece to [0,1]?

Comment: Can you post the data for the example time series, as well as the highs and low points? Also, since there are a number of ways to do this, can you say anything more about what constraints you want the result to obey, what properties it ought to preserve, etc.?

Comment: I thought about cutting up the series and scaling each section, but it would be preferable for the transformation to be based on a smooth function.  I’m going to use the transformed series for prediction purposes, so creating breakpoints might not be ideal.

Comment: As for the peak/trough logic, the emphasis is on the peaks/troughs in the middle.  Given a threshold and some data, the middle peaks/troughs should always be the same once the series deviates from the first point by more than the threshold, but different rules can be set for the beginning and end of the series.  And yes, the peaks and troughs will always alternate.  The series above is just a random walk created with numpy in python.